# Python Image Library Additive Blending

Tags: python, image, blending

How can I additively blend two images?

I am trying to create random polygons and I'd like to layer them up.

I have tried Image.Blend and Image.paste however they just 'replace' the pixel values.

I would like to intensify images if that makes sense. So two images that are half transparent, will layer down to a fully opaque image.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved with the [ImageChops](http://python.developpez.com/cours/pilhandbook/php/imagechops.php) module: If you want the "average" of two images (channel-wise), simply use

```
ImageChops.add(image1, image2, 2)
```

(The last parameter causes the "sum" of the images to be divided by 2.) Depending on what exactly you want, `ImageChops.multiply` might also be useful.